# Compute the log density in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a function in EstimaRATS, that is use to compute the required normal density.

```
The function %LOGDENSITY (VARAINCE,X) computes the required Normal density
```

Would anyone happen to know how I could do the same thing in MATLAB.

Comment: I think you should go for [`mvnpdf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnpdf.html) (Multivariate normal probability density function), more documentation [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/multivariate-normal-distribution.html).

Comment: [`normpdf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normpdf.html)? Or do it manually, the formula is simple